# Exchange 2010 periodically stops responding to SMTP events with error 421 4.4.1 Connection timed out

Tags: exchange, smtp, exchange-2010

After some help diagnosing why Exchange 2010 Enterprise stops responding to SMTP events.

I can't find a pattern to it.  It doesn't appear to be an *actual* timeout, as the server responds immediately with the error.  To reproduce it I telnet into the server on port 25 and issue a `EHLO`.  The server immediately replies with the 421:

> 421 4.4.1 Connection timed out

Once this starts happening I've found restarting the exchange box is the only reliable way to get it flowing again.  Sometimes restarting the Transport service or the mailbox attendant service seems to fix it, but this could be coincidental as it often has no effect.

Comment: getting exactly the same issue on one of my servers, has anyone found a solution for this yet

Comment: No - I decided it was a better use of my time to move to hosted exchange.  Couple of months now and no noticeable downtime, wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

thanks Michael did some research could be related to resource usage, have added some extra memory to teh VM will see if it fixes it. here is a link with some info for anyone else having the same issue 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb201658.aspx